# I am having trouble bluetooth-sharing pictures from my cell phone. It works on my 2017 iMac, but not on my M2 Mini

Tags: bluetooth, mac-mini

I'm having trouble getting Bluetooth sharing to work on my M2 Mini. I can pair the two devices (the mini and my LG VN220) just fine. But I can't send pictures to the Mini.

I rarely have trouble sending pictures to my 2017 iMac, but that system is to be decommissioned and given to somebody else, as soon as I iron out all the bugs on the Mini.

At first, it rejected pictures because Bluetooth sharing wasn't enabled in System Settings. I turned it on, and it accepted one picture (but didn't ask me to confirm!)

I then turned on confirmation, and tried to send a picture: no confirmation dialog appeared, and my phone timed out without sending anything.

I tried turning confirmation off, and sending again. Still nothing.

I tried unpairing and repairing, and shutting down and restarting the phone. Still nothing.

But it continues to work on the 2017 iMac.

I could of course transfer pictures on a mini-SD card, the way I do with my old "bionic desk lamp" iMac at home, or with my Chromebook, but then I'd need to add a memory card reader.

Current Bluetooth sharing parameters on Mini (fails):

- When receiving items: Accept and Save
- Folder for accepted items: Downloads
- When other devices browse: Ask what to do
- Folder others can browse: Public

Bluetooth is turned on, and paired with my phone. As I said, it worked exactly once, and then when I changed it to "Ask what to do," it failed, and continued to fail even after I changed it back.

Current Bluetooth sharing parameters on 2017 iMac (works, most of the time):

- When receiving items: Ask what to do
- Folder for accepted items: Downloads
- When other devices browse: Always allow
- Folder others can browse: Public

Comment: What have you set as parameters for bluetooth sharing?

Comment: @Thinkr: Parameters added

Comment: Your parameters look fine, but try setting a different destination for files.  Try setting it to your Desktop.  If it works, set it back to Downloads

Comment: @Allan: No change.

Comment: Just for grins and giggles, create a new account (just for testing), log into that and see if it works there. Let’s see if this is user thing or something systemwide

Comment: @Allan: No change.

Comment: Ok.  This is systemwide.  Do you have access to a Mac running a different version of macOS than the one you’re on now?  If so, can you try there?

Comment: Sorry.  I forgot you had a 2017 Mac.   What version macOS is on that one?  Ventura as well?

Comment: @Allan: What I *CAN* do is successfully send pictures from my phone to the "backup controller" Mini (the one running Yosemite, in my threads about automated backups from AS/400s and spontaneously disconnecting USB hard drives). The 2017 iMac is on Catalina, BTW.

Comment: I was hoping you’d say Ventura.  My father has an iMac with Catalina (where I am now) and his Android works fine sending photos.  I’m trying to replicate this here, but I’ve run out Macs to try on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ***am,*** however, able to successfully Bluetooth-share pictures with an old Mac Mini (running Yosemite) that hosts an automated backup server for a couple of IBM Midrange (i.e., AS/400) boxes. And I'm planning on hosting a couple of shared directories on the Yosemite box as well, that were originally Samba shares on the Linux box it replaced.

And unlike the iMac, it's not slated to be decommissioned and sent elsewhere.